# Как динамически добавлять контент в верх таблицы?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

Привет всем! Вопрос такой, как реализовать добавление контента в верх таблицы, чтобы сама таблица не скролилась, а оставалась на том же месте что и до добавление контента.

Пробовал отслеживать положение футера верхней секции, и при его появлении добавлять контент в массив и делать `tableView.reloadData()` но таблица автоматом прокручивается и опять вызывает метод загрузки данных. Пробовал так же добавлять новые секции с помощью метода `insertSection`, всё тоже самое. Так же пробовал делать таблице свойство `scrollEnabled = false` на время загрузки данных, тоже не помогло.

Делать `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` на ячейку на которой произошла загрузка, после добавления контента тоже не вариант, т.к будут поддергивания

В итоге хочется получить примерно так как реализовано в мобильном приложении ВК при просмотре обсуждений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант:

- отслеживать `contentOffset` таблицы, когда дошла до верха
- добавить новую ячейку сверху `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` без анимации
- сдвинуть `contentOffset` таким образом, чтобы он опять был там же, где и до добавления ячеек.

Что надо помнить: не желательно это делать пока юзер 'тянет' таблицу, получится неожиданный эффект. Лучше отслеживать и добавлять когда юзер перестал тянуть.

Comment: да это работает, но конечно не идеально как хотелось бы. Мне тут еще один вариант подсказали, можно перевернуть UITableView и все ячейки в нём на 180 градусов, тогда подгрузка данных должна быть поплавнее, т.к. скролл в этом случае не будет дергатся, но сам этот вариант еще не пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно из вопроса чем не устраивает

```
 [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(nonnull NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>];
```

Не делайте `reloadData;`
Используйте

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(nonnull NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: этот метод при добавлении ячеек и секций в верх таблицы, скролит таблицу, а мне нужно чтобы таблица была на той ячейки где и до добавления. И почему-то при добавлении таким способом приложение иногда падает, при быстром скролинге, с релоад дата таких проблем нет.

Comment: Попробуйте сетить contentOffset перед эндапдейт  |[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, iContentOffset)];
[tableView endUpdates];